# Breaking down scene to modular pieces

Tags: modeling, export, scene

### Can i build my entire model within the same scene, then export each piece individually so that they're modular in UE4?

Or do i have to build each piece within its own scene and export separately.

**For example**

i made 10x1x10 wall and then duplicated it and used the same dimensions with a door cutout in the second piece and then selected the first mesh to export into UE.

But when i went into UE4 both pieces were there meaning Blender exported everything in the scene.

So how do i just export the pieces i want one by one after building the entire model?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each object can be exported as a separate FBX file. Just select one and check the Selected Objects in the export settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million!.I knew i should be able to select and export individual parts, Can't believe i didn't see and check that box. Thank you

Comment: @Mingo Please consider mark answer as accepted by clicking on checkmark bellow wote arrows. So other can see it as solved from main list. Thank you